# Cassandra query logs and performance

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

1) Is there a way to **log the queries executed** in Cassandra?
2) For performance, I understand TracingON in cqlsh is a good feature for tracing the single query we execute in cqlsh. But Is there a way to **profile the Cassandra queries** which gives the execution time, query data size etc.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracing isn't just limited to CQL. You could enable the same behavior from Java code as well.

Set the tracing flag on the Statement instance. There are various ways depending on how you build it:

```
// Setter-based:
Statement statement =
  SimpleStatement.newInstance("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1234").setTracing(true);

// Builder-based:
Statement statement =
  SimpleStatement.builder("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1234").withTracing().build();
```

Here is the detailed [reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.0-alpha/manual/core/tracing/)

Comment: Is it available only for Java driver (or) Is it also available for c++ or nodejs driver?

Comment: Because am not able to find for c++ driver

Comment: can you please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385262/cassandra-commit-log-size

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432926/native-transport-requests-in-cassandra