# Cassandra batch prepared statement size warning

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I see this error continuously in the debug.log in cassandra,

```
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2018-05-16 08:33:48,585 BatchStatement.java:287 - Batch of prepared statements for [test, test1] is of size 6419, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 1299.
```

In this

```
   where,
                    6419 - Input payload size (Batch)
                    5120 - Threshold size
                    1299 - Byte size above threshold value
```

so as per this ticket in Cassandra, https://github.com/krasserm/akka-persistence-cassandra/issues/33 I see that it is due to the increase in input payload size so I Increased the `commitlog_segment_size_in_mb` in cassandra.yml to `60mb` and we are not facing this warning anymore.

Is this Warning harmful? Increasing the commitlog_segment_size_in_mb will it affect anything in performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not related to the commit log size directly, and I wonder why its change lead to disappearing of the warning...

The batch size threshold is controlled by `batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb` parameter that is default to 5kb (5120 bytes).

You can increase this parameter to higher value, but you really need to have good reason for using batches - it would be nice to understand the context of their usage...

Comment: I am using this batch query for transaction, Is this warning harmful? Increasing the 'batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb' will it impact the application? I got confused with this ticket : https://github.com/krasserm/akka-persistence-cassandra/issues/33

Comment: Warning is not very harmful, but you need to control how big are you batches, so set it to reasonable value...

Comment: I really don't understand why in this ticket, people are changing the wrong setting...

Comment: What will be the consequence of the huge batch size ?

Comment: Usually huge batch size means a lot of individual statements. The consequences are really dependent on the type of batch, and data in the batch - are they for same partition, or not, etc. Check sections on good & wrong use of batches at https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchTOC.html

Comment: Another treat for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432926/native-transport-requests-in-cassandra Please do the needful :)

Answer (score -1):

commit_log_segment_size_in_mb represents your block size for commit log archiving or point-in-time backup. These are only active if you have configured archive_command or restore_command in your commitlog_archiving.properties file.
Default size is 32mb.

As per Expert Apache Cassandra Administration book:

```
you must ensure that value of commitlog_segment_size_in_mb must be twice the value of max_mutation_size_in_kb.
```

you can take reference of this:

[Mutation of 17076203 bytes is too large for the maxiumum size of 16777216](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513776/mutation-of-17076203-bytes-is-too-large-for-the-maxiumum-size-of-16777216)

Comment: Thank for responding, But as per another StackOverflow link provided, I could see that Cassandra can accept (commitlog_segment_size_in_mb / 2) times the data size in the payload. But why is that throwing threshold error for 5KB? I have commitlog_segment_size_in_mb value as 32MB, What is the significane of 5KB in it?

Comment: also I would like to know Is this warning harmful? Please give some light

Comment: The title of the question is incorrect - this message is related to completely different setting...